# Не работает выравнивание inline-блоков по ширине в IE

Tags: css

На [сайте](http://victorpavloff.tmweb.ru/dev/HP3/) в блоке "Этапы работы" каждый из этапов в списке представлен. как inline-block. Этапы выровнены по ширине.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="stages_list">
    <div class="stage">Заявка</div>
    <div class="stage">Коммерческое предложение</span></div>
    <div class="stage">Счет и оплата</div>
    <div class="stage">Отгрузка и доставка</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#stages .stages_list {
    margin: 32px 0 50px 0;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    text-align: justify;
    -moz-text-align-last: justify;
    text-align-last: justify;
}

#stages .stages_list:before{
    display: block;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
}

#stages .stages_list:after {
    display: inline-block;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#stages .stages_list .stage {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "ProximaNovaRegular";
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}
```

В IE блоки выравниваются не по ширине, а слева.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать выравнивание по ширине?

Comment: В IE11 у вас та же проблема ;)

Comment: между дивами оставляйте отступы! Если всё блоки слитно, то воспринимается, как одно слово.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#stages .stages_list {
    margin: 32px 0 50px 0;
    # font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    text-align: justify;
    -moz-text-align-last: justify;
    text-align-last: justify;
}
```

font-size: 0 закомментируйте

Comment: Теперь выравнивается. Хотелось бы понять, почему :-)

Comment: Точно не знаю, но могу лишь предположить! В IE для правильного выравнивания блока необходимо получить размер шрифта в элементе, где задаётся выравнивание (#stages .stages_list). Другие же браузеры, просчитывают размеры шрифтов вложенных элементов.